Why is this Windows Forms Button getting small when I run the app?
I was doing a small app to show a buddy how to do a basic UI with some buttons and stuff. Thing is, everything was going fine... until it was not. Literally. I added a new button the same way I added the others and it appears small, with no text, in another X-Y position... you name it.
An image is worth a thousand words, so...
How it should look:

How it actually looks:

I created more buttons and the same happens. If I set the values in the Form_Load Sub it works, but the thing is that it shouldn't be giving me problems as is. I copied and pasted the other buttons, too. Same result.

Did you look in the Properties window? Are the property values what you expect? Does the same thing happen on a different form? In a different project?

Is the object anchored properly?
Open properties and make sure its anchored to top and left.
If thats not the problem, it may be an issue with the designer.cs file or your custom object.
